# Add items to paginator laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So i have a problem when i want to add element to Paginator collection, i got this error :

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Support\Collection' does not have a method 'add'
```

This is my code :

```
$data = $users->whereBetween('program_date',[$from,$to . ' 23:59:59'])->paginate(10);
$tests = $test->whereBetween('created_at',[$from,$to . ' 23:59:59'])->paginate(10);

foreach ($tests as $sms) {
    $camp = new Campagne();
    $camp->user_id = $sms->user_id;
    $data->add($camp); // i got error in this line!!
}
```

so please if someone has any idea how to use **->add($element)** with laravel pagination i will be very appreciative.

Comment: I think you need only $data['camp'] = $camp will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Collection has a function called add. also I am not sure you can loop through, at least not the models, with straight from Paginator. I believe you need to change it to

```
foreach( $tests->getItems() as $sms ){
  .....
}
```

the reason it won't work this way is when you paginate a collection you get an instance of Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator class and when you loop through, you are basically looping class object not your items.